# Recycler view adapter animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

After searching on SO, I have this piece of code to animate the appear animation of items in RecyclerView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CourseViewHolder courseViewHolder, final int i) {
    courseViewHolder.courseDate.setText(courseList.get(i).year);
    courseViewHolder.courseName.setText(courseList.get(i).name);

    setAnimation(courseViewHolder.view, i);

    courseViewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onClick(view, i);
        }
    });
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}
```

It kinda works, however the animation of all the items start at the same time. Is this possible to slide the items one by one? I thought about having a `Handler` to pass the delay after animating an item, but it does not work and I don't know where to put it (the `onBindViewHolder` still manages to show all the items at once).

Another question, where could I put the code to animate the disappear animation of all items in adapter? something to run when you refresh the RecyclerView in the `OnRefreshListener` of the SwipeRefreshLayout in your activity.